# Calculate rolling difference with multiple grouping conditions in R

Tags: r

Here is the data:

```
structure(list(country = c("Australia", "Australia", "Australia", 
"Australia", "Australia", "Australia", "Australia", "Australia", 
"Australia", "New Zealand", "New Zealand", "New Zealand", "New Zealand", 
"New Zealand", "New Zealand", "New Zealand", "New Zealand", "New Zealand"
), year = c(1999L, 1999L, 1999L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 1999L, 1999L, 1999L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L), class = c("Big fish", "Big fish", "Small fish", 
"Big fish", "Big fish", "Small fish", "Big fish", "Big fish", 
"Small fish", "Big fish", "Big fish", "Small fish", "Big fish", 
"Big fish", "Small fish", "Big fish", "Big fish", "Small fish"
), location = c("AAA", "B", "AAA", "AAA", "B", "AAA", "AAA", 
"B", "AAA", "AAA", "B", "AAA", "AAA", "B", "AAA", "AAA", "B", 
"AAA"), value = c(20, 7, 0.1, 15, 14, 0.1, 30, 28, 0.1, 250, 
1000, 30, 100, 2000, 60, 0, 2500, 90)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-18L))
```

```
country     year    class       location  value
Australia   1999    Big fish    AAA       20
Australia   1999    Big fish    B         7
Australia   1999    Small fish  AAA       0.1
Australia   2005    Big fish    AAA       15
Australia   2005    Big fish    B         14
Australia   2005    Small fish  AAA       0.1
Australia   2018    Big fish    AAA       30
Australia   2018    Big fish    B         28
Australia   2018    Small fish  AAA       0.1
New Zealand 1999    Big fish    AAA       250
New Zealand 1999    Big fish    B         1000
New Zealand 1999    Small fish  AAA       30
New Zealand 2005    Big fish    AAA       100
New Zealand 2005    Big fish    B         2000
New Zealand 2005    Small fish  AAA       60
New Zealand 2018    Big fish    AAA       0
New Zealand 2018    Big fish    B         2500
New Zealand 2018    Small fish  AAA       90
```

I want to calculate the rolling difference of the value of each class*location group between inconsecutive years within each country, the expected outcome looks like this:

```
country     year difference class       location    value difference
Australia   6               Big fish    AAA         -5
Australia   6               Big fish    B           7
Australia   6               Small fish  AAA         0
Australia   13              Big fish    AAA         15
Australia   13              Big fish    B           14
Australia   13              Small fish  AAA         0
New Zealand 6               Big fish    AAA         -150
New Zealand 6               Big fish    B           1000
New Zealand 6               Small fish  AAA         30
New Zealand 13              Big fish    AAA         -100
New Zealand 13              Big fish    B           500
New Zealand 13              Small fish  AAA         30
```

I tried `dplyr::group_by()`, but it seemed that `group_by()` doesn't simply work with this data structure, so I'm wonder how should I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a `data.table` approach

```
library(data.table)
# set to data.table format
setDT(mydata)
# calculate differences
mydata[, `:=`(diff_year = year - shift(year),
              diff_val = value - shift(value)), by = .(country, class, location)]
# drop rows without previous years
mydata[!is.na(diff_year), ]
#        country year      class location  value diff_year diff_val
# 1:   Australia 2005   Big fish      AAA   15.0         6       -5
# 2:   Australia 2005   Big fish        B   14.0         6        7
# 3:   Australia 2005 Small fish      AAA    0.1         6        0
# 4:   Australia 2018   Big fish      AAA   30.0        13       15
# 5:   Australia 2018   Big fish        B   28.0        13       14
# 6:   Australia 2018 Small fish      AAA    0.1        13        0
# 7: New Zealand 2005   Big fish      AAA  100.0         6     -150
# 8: New Zealand 2005   Big fish        B 2000.0         6     1000
# 9: New Zealand 2005 Small fish      AAA   60.0         6       30
#10: New Zealand 2018   Big fish      AAA    0.0        13     -100
#11: New Zealand 2018   Big fish        B 2500.0        13      500
#12: New Zealand 2018 Small fish      AAA   90.0        13       30
```

Answer (score 0):

supporting @Wimpel answer, you can aggragate and filter values, it is kinda same thing with what @Wimpel suggest, but I just want to comment that it is also easily possible in dplyr, but datatable package is more reasonable and preferable for bigdata.

```
mydata <- structure(list(country = c("Australia", "Australia", "Australia", 
                           "Australia", "Australia", "Australia", "Australia", "Australia", 
                           "Australia", "New Zealand", "New Zealand", "New Zealand", "New Zealand", 
                           "New Zealand", "New Zealand", "New Zealand", "New Zealand", "New Zealand"
), year = c(1999L, 1999L, 1999L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2018L, 
            2018L, 2018L, 1999L, 1999L, 1999L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2018L, 
            2018L, 2018L), class = c("Big fish", "Big fish", "Small fish", 
                                     "Big fish", "Big fish", "Small fish", "Big fish", "Big fish", 
                                     "Small fish", "Big fish", "Big fish", "Small fish", "Big fish", 
                                     "Big fish", "Small fish", "Big fish", "Big fish", "Small fish"
            ), location = c("AAA", "B", "AAA", "AAA", "B", "AAA", "AAA", 
                            "B", "AAA", "AAA", "B", "AAA", "AAA", "B", "AAA", "AAA", "B", 
                            "AAA"), value = c(20, 7, 0.1, 15, 14, 0.1, 30, 28, 0.1, 250, 
                                              1000, 30, 100, 2000, 60, 0, 2500, 90)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                          -18L))


library(dplyr)

mydata %>% 
  group_by(country, class, location) %>% 
  summarize(diff_year = year - lag(year),
         diff_val = value - lag(value)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  filter(!is.na(diff_year) | !is.na(diff_val))
```

Comment: I got an error with dplyr 1.1.0, and it worked after changing `summarize()` to `reframe()`.
The error message:
```Error: (converted from warning) Returning more (or less) than 1 row per `summarise()` group was deprecated in dplyr 1.1.0.
ℹ Please use `reframe()` instead.
ℹ When switching from `summarise()` to `reframe()`, remember that `reframe()` always returns an ungrouped data frame and adjust accordingly.```

Comment: I think, it is becasue you are using older version of dplyr,

> packageVersion("dplyr")
 ‘1.1.2’